# How to edit stylesheet for QProgressBar

Tags: python, css, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

I can't edit colors for progress bar in my app. Edited only text color.

```
pyhton: 3.9
PySide6
QT Creator: 7.0.2
```

[Python app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hKFI.png)

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtWidgets


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.progress = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress.setObjectName(u"progress")
        self.progress.setValue(80)
        self.progress.setStyleSheet("color: red;\n"
                                    "background-color: blue;\n"
                                    "selection-background-color: yellow;")
        self.progress.repaint()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.resize(200, 80)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

But this styles are working at QTCreator
[QTCreator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zIrv.png)

Answer (score 2):

To edit background of progress I needed to use this stylesheet:

```py
self.setStyleSheet("""
    QProgressBar {
        border: 2px solid rgba(33, 37, 43, 180);
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: rgba(33, 37, 43, 180);
        color: black;
    }
    QProgressBar::chunk {
        background-color: #FFD700;
    }
""")
```